# Многопоточный чат на сокетах

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь реализовать графический многопоточный чат на сокетах с использованием JavaFX, но не могу понять, как происходить обмен сообщениями между клиентами и сервером. Окно приложение элементарное: TextArea, TextField и Button. Вообщем, пишешь текст в TextField, нажимаешь кнопку и отправляешь сооб. на сервер. А сервер отправляет сооб. на TextArea. Вот как я попытался это сделать:

Client.java

```
package objects;

import controllers.stageController;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;

    public Client(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        System.out.println("New client connected.\r\n\tInetAdress: " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try(InputStream in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out))) {

            stageController sc = new stageController();
            String string1 = null;
            String string2 = null;

            while(clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("hello");

                /* По нажатию на кнопку отправлять сообщение серверу */
//                try{
//                    string1 = sc.getMsg(); // Вот тут NPE
//                } catch(NullPointerException e) {continue;}
//                if(!string1.isEmpty() && string1 != null) {
//                    bufferedWriter.write(string1);
//                    System.out.println("Client has send the message");
//                }
                /*****************************************************/

                /* Принимать сообщение от сервера */
//                if((string2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
//                    sc.receive(string2 + "\r\n");
//                    System.out.println("Client received the message");
//                }
                /**********************************/
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in Client class!");
        }
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
package objects;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public final static int port = 5555;
    private static Map<String, String> clientInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static List<Client>        clientList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Server() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server created.\r\n\tPort: " + port + "\r\n\tInetAdress: " + serverSocket.getInetAddress());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in server`s constructor");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                Client client = new Client(serverSocket.accept());
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(client);
                clientList.add(client);
                clientThread.setDaemon(true); // Теперь этот поток будет завершаться при закрытии главного окна
                clientThread.start();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException in Server.run()");
        }
    }

    public final static void addClient(String login, String parol) {
        clientInfo.put(login, parol);
    }

    public final static boolean isPresent(String login, String parol) {
        return clientInfo.get(login) != null && (clientInfo.get(login)).equals(parol);
    }
}
```

stageController.java

```
package controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class stageController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea ta;
    @FXML
    private TextField tf;

    private String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public final void send(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        msg = tf.getText();
        tf.clear();
    }

    public final void receive(String msg) {
        ta.setText(msg + "\r\n");
    }
}
```

Метод main

```
Server server = new Server();
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
        serverThread.setDaemon(true); // Теперь этот поток будет завершаться при закрытии главного окна
        serverThread.start();

        launch(args);
```

Answer (score 1):

У тебя сервер хранит список всех подключений в `clientList`. Соответственно, чтобы отправить всем сообщения, нужно в цикле пройтись по этому списку, и записать в `OutputStream` каждого клиента очередное сообщение, которое пришло серверу. Как-то так...

Comment: Вы правы, но в данном случае это проблему не решит потому, что чат с ГПИ и эти сообщения выводятся на TextArea и пользователь их увидит. Проблема в том, что в классе Client, в строке string1=sc.getMsg() вылетает NPE, которое блокирует поток. Как с этим быть?

Comment: @Денис Савенко, в классе `stageController` поле `msg` инициализируется в методе `send(ActionEvent actionEvent)` . Я не вижу где ты его вызываешь. А если нет вызова этого метода, то `msg`  остается `null`